# Dropdown in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am new to MVC so probably confused .  can somebody please explain me the dropdown in razor.my questions are-

- What is the difference in dropdownlist and dropdownlistfor
- how do i Pass ID column of my database  table as value and NAME column as text.
- How do i add "other" to the dropdownlist.
- how do i access the selectedlistitem in code behind.

if possible please explain with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DropDownList is generated by code like this:

   ```
   @Html.DropDownList("PersonId", new SelectList(Model.People, "Id", "Text");
   ```

   On the other hand, DropDownListFor is generated like this:

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonId, new SelectList(Model.People, "Id", "Text")
   ```

   Problem with DropDownList is that it has a magic string and if you decide to refactor the model later on, there's a high change you'll forget to change the magic string too.
2. You could do a LINQ query like this:

   ```
   var datalist = New SelectList(from x in _peopleService
                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id});
   ```

   If you don't have a service or an ORM between it you need to apply it to your situation, but you can generate a list like that.
3. After nr 2, you can

   ```
   datalist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Other", Value = "-1"});
   ```

   Also you have to put that datalist in your viewmodel/model that is passed to the View, so you can generate a selectlist item with that. In this case you could just do:

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PersonId, Model.PersonList);
   ```

   if you stored the list as PersonList in Model.
4. In your Viewmodel (Well, model in mvc) you have a property where the selected item will be stored, look at the 1st question - In this instance the selected item's id will be stored in the PersonId property.

Comment: you could probably mention how enums and dropdowns work together aswell. I usually have an enum for a dropdown. :)